# Prevent screen recording in the app

Tags: android

As suggested in other threads I have used FLAG_SECURE to prevent recording but it only works in portrait mode. When I rotate and play the movie in landscape mode, it doesn't prevent recording. Can anyone help me out??

Answer (score 0):

> put this code into your OnResume()

```
getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```